# Specific type implementation for generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to provide a type specific implementation for a Java method?

Given a data class like:

```
class Message<T> {
   String messageId;
   T value;
```

I have a method that reads a text format (json) and creates an instance of this class. Values can be either String or Integer.

```
class MessageReader {
    public <T> Message<T> read(final Json json) {
        return Message.<T>build()
            .messageId(json.get("id").getAsString())
            .value(<T>readValue(json))
            .build();
    }

    // This can not be done since the method to get the value is different for String and Integer
    private <T> T readValue(Json json) {
        return json.get("value").getAsString() // or .getAsInteger() depending on T
    }

    // What I would like to do
    private <String> String readValue(Json json) {
        return json.get("value").getAsString();
    }
    private <Integer> Integer readValue(Json json) {
        return json.get("value").getAsInteger();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Java? (something like C++ capabilities)

Comment: If the _caller_ can't choose what type they want, then your method shouldn't be generic. It seems like `read` and `readValue` should return `Message<?>` and `Object` respectively instead.

Comment: Good point about the caller being able to select the type or not. Actually, in my use case the caller get's to set the expected type, meaning that the caller expected something like Message<String> or Message<Integer>. (My use case is a functional test where the message received should conform with the type expected)

Answer (score 1):

Not like this. Java generics are not C++ templates: generics are simply compiler-inserted (and compiler-checked) casts. If you can't do something yourself with casts, you can't do it with generics.

You have to pass in something which is specialized to extracting the type you want from the input, e.g.

```
private <T> T readValue(Json json, Function<? super Json, ? extends T> fn) {
  return fn.apply(json);
}
```

which you invoke like:

```
String str = readValue(json, json -> json.get("value").getAsString());
```

but by the time you've got to write that much, a generic helper method isn't saving you anything:

```
String str = json.get("value").getAsString();
```

Non-generic helper methods are a better approach:

```
private String readValueAsString(Json json) {
    return json.get("value").getAsString();
}
private Integer readValueAsInteger(Json json) {
    return json.get("value").getAsInteger();
}
```

Sure, you have to pick the "right name". But I'd take that over the attempt at using generics.

Comment: So if I understood correctly I should expose 2 separate methods (one per type) like: `public Message<String> readAsString(...)` and `public Message<Integer> readAsInteger(...)`; isn't it? The common pieces could be shared with private methods I guess.

That should work, but It might not scale well if the Message ends up being parameterized with multiple types `Message<T, R>`; either way that's not my case as of now, just curious. Thanks!